# prevent video from being downloaded

Tags: php, video-streaming

I am using flowplayer for playing video and audio in a lightbox. I want to play the videos on the site but users should not be able to download it. The link to files should not be visible in the page source to use it to download it directly. For flowplayer they mention 2 modules lightppd and wowza but I have to make server side changes which I do not want to do. Is there any other way to do secure streaming of video content to the page to only play and not be able to download it?

Comment: if you can show it on the web site a user can copy it

Comment: youtube videos are not meant to be downloaded and yet I can download them using add-ons.. point is, it can't be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play a video on a web page the user MUST download it to view it... Add-ons that allow you to download media content just scoop into the transfer and copy the downloaded data into a file.

Even IF you encrypt or secure the video content, the user is still able to download the video and may be able to crack the security at a later time.

Short answer, not possible.

Comment: +1 Or they'll just screen capture it..

Comment: not totally secured streaming but i achieved secure streaming to some extend.

Comment: http://goldprogramming.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Its one of my most voted answer. A webpage on remote users's machine is out of server's control. Anything on the page is on user's machine. That's the whole idea of web. Look here [How to stop user from printing webpages? using javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647392/how-to-stop-user-from-printing-webpages-using-javascript-or-jquery/6647410#6647410)

Comment: You should comment the same :)