# Close print preview popup or prevent to open jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Designing html for printing in iframe with onload event in body tag. i want to prevent popup print preview dialog or close automatically when open, but not getting any success yet.

i have tried with remove remove attibute, unbind, off.

anybody have idea to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop user from printing webpages? using javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647392/how-to-stop-user-from-printing-webpages-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the print pop, but you can use print @media CSS to hide

```
@media print {
  html, body {
    display: none;  /* hide whole page */
  }
}
```